# Как построить графики на основе DataFrame из всех файлов в одной папке?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, графика, matplotlib

Как открыть все файлы в одной папке и нарисовать графики столбца?

[Файлы](https://dropmefiles.com/duzGn).

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

p = Path(r"result")

for f in p.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df["Close"].plot() 
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если нужно нарисовать каждый столбец на **отдельном** графике:

```
df = (pd
      .concat([pd
               .read_csv(f, 
                         usecols=["Date", "Close"], 
                         parse_dates=["Date"], 
                         index_col="Date")
               .rename(columns={"Close":f.stem})
               for f in p.glob("*.csv")], 
              axis=1))

df.plot(subplots=True, sharey=True, grid=True)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD:** чтобы нарисовать данные из каждого файла, но так, чтобы данные из одного файла были нарисованы в собственном новом окне:

```
for f in p.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, 
                     usecols=["Date", "Close"],
                     parse_dates=["Date"], 
                     index_col="Date")
    df[f.stem] = df.pop("Close")
    df.plot(grid=True, figsize=(8, 4))
```

Comment: @Ivan_h, можете понятнее объяснить - что вы хотите получить? Вы хотите 10 графиков, __по одному графику в файле__??

Comment: @Ivan_h, т.е. вы хотите получить 10 окошек  - в каждом по графику?

Comment: @Ivan_h, см. UPD: ...

Answer (score 1):

```
p = Path(r"result")

df = (pd
      .concat([pd
               .read_csv(f, 
                         usecols=["Date", "Close"], 
                         parse_dates=["Date"], 
                         index_col="Date")
               .rename(columns={"Close":f.stem})
               for f in p.glob("*.csv")], 
              axis=1))

df.plot()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Ivan_h, [подсказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143278/211923) ;)

Answer (score 1):

> как это сделать по отдельности - один график - одна линия?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6)) 
 
for f in p.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, 
                     usecols=["Date", "Close"],
                     parse_dates=["Date"], 
                     index_col="Date")
    df[f.stem] = df.pop("Close")
    df.plot(grid=True, ax=ax)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]